# My ipad is only uploading in .jpg format is this my fault?

Tags: php, ios, ipad, file-upload

My upload script is fine on my laptop if i upload .png it shows .png but if i try to using my ipad ios 7.0.x the image type is always .jpg

```
if ( isset( $_FILES["image_file"] ) ) {

    $image_file = $_FILES["image_file"]["name"];
    $image_ext = pathinfo( $image_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
    $image_name = remove_bad_words( str_replace( " ", "_", $title ), "/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s_]/" ) . "." . $image_ext;
    $folder_location = "../images/tech/";

    if ( $_FILES["image_file"]["error"] > 0 ) {

        $errors[] = $_FILES["image_file"]["error"];
    }

    if ( file_exists( $folder_location . $image_name ) ) {

        $_SESSION["message"] .= "{$image_name} already exists, ";

    } else {

        $_SESSION["message"] .= "{$image_name} was uploaded successfully, ";

        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["image_file"]["tmp_name"],  $folder_location . $image_name );
    }
}
```

Is it me or my ipad ?

Ps i know this script is unsafe it is for testing purposes.

Comment: How do you know you're not actually uploading JPGs from your iPad?

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton I have downloaded lots of .png to test